# NSAttributedString extension in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm migrating my code to swift 3 and I'm having a hard time with this extension that was working on the previous swift version.

```
extension Data {
    var attributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options:[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now when I try to call this piece of code I get an exception error like this

```
error: warning: couldn't get required object pointer (substituting NULL): Couldn't load 'self' because its value couldn't be evaluated
```

That's how I call the method from my view controller

```
let htmlCode = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: Avenir-Roman}body {font-family: Avenir-Roman;font-size:15;margin: 0;padding: 0}</style></head><body bgcolor=\"#FBFBFB\">" + htmlBodyCode + "</body>"
newsDescription.attributedText = htmlCode.utf8Data?.attributedString
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
extension Data {
    var attributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options:[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

As described in [the official reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nscharacterencodingdocumentattribute), the value for key `NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute` needs to be an `NSNumber`.

> **NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute**
>
> The value of this attribute is an `NSNumber` object containing integer specifying `NSStringEncoding`
> for the file;

In older Swifts, `NSStringEncoding` constants are imported as `UInt`s, so they are automatically bridged to `NSNumber` when converted to `AnyObject`, as contained in `NSDictionary`.

But now, Swift introduced a new enum type `String.Encoding` which is not originated as an Objective-C enum. And unfortunately, now any Swift types can be contained in an `NSDictionary` with intermediate hidden reference type `_SwiftValue`, which definitely is NOT an `NSNumber`.

So, you need to pass something which can be bridged to `NSNumber` as the value for key `NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute`. In your case, `rawValue` would work.

In my opinion, this should be improved, and better send a bug report to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) or [swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org/).

Comment: Thanks! However, since I was using a modified font I had to add one more catch: catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } catch {
                print("Description Error")
            }

Answer (score 32):

In case anyone needs assistance in **Swift 5.2+** :

```
extension Data {
    var attributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self, options: [ NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue ], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```